# Como incluir una 'd' en un formato de fecha

Tags: c#, date, formato

estoy intentando hacer que la fecha me la muestre de la siguiente manera: 14 de abril del 2020, en c# por lo cual lo hice de la siguiente forma

```
fechaEmision.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd de MMMM del yyyy");
```

pero esto me muestra la fecha asi: 14 14e abril 14el 2020, remplazandome las 'd' por el dia. alguna forma simple de hacerlo?

Answer (score 2):

Eso pasa porque `d` en la cadena significa día. Para que te acepte la letra sin un significado especial tienes que  usar el caracter de escape `\`:

```
date.ToString("dd \\de MMMM \\del yyyy")
```

Otra forma:

```
date.ToString(@"dd \de MMMM \del yyyy")
```

Answer (score 2):

Envuelve 'de' y 'del' con comillas simples de la siguiente manera para que no te reconozca la d como día o cualquier otro carácter especial de formato contenido

```
fechaEmision.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd 'de' MMMM 'del' yyyy");
```